# select variable from json into empty column of table with existing records

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table containing multiple columns one of which is a jsonb object. I want to create a new column from one of the json variables, but the update command appends to the bottom of the table.

I have:

```
time    info    id    some_json
12      bla           {"id":"123","more_info":"bla bla"}
13      bla           {"id":"124","more_info":"bla bla"}
```

I need:

```
time    info    id    some_json
12      bla     123   {"id":"123","more_info":"bla bla"}
13      bla     124   {"id":"124","more_info":"bla bla"}
```

I get:

```
time    info    id    some_json
12      bla           {"id":"123","more_info":"bla bla"}
13      bla           {"id":"124","more_info":"bla bla"}
                123
                124
```

When I use `insert_into my_table(id) select some_json ->> 'id' from my_table;`

What is the correct way to do this? I'm a SQL beginner and plenty of commands sound like they would be the right for the job (update, insert, select into, alter).

Answer (score 0):

you need update not insert

```
update my_table
set id= case when time=12 then select some_json ->> 'id' from my_table where time=12
             when time 13 then select some_json ->> 'id' from my_table where time=13 end;
```

Comment: I have many more entries and I can't specify a time constrait every time. Is there a possiblity to do it without such?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a simple update statement

```
update t set id = (some_json->>'id')::int;
                                   --^ cast it to the datatype of id column
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=2076bc9a6d6df75125fabdae96d3b156)